# How to test whether a system command exist in Java

Tags: java, runtime, exec

I am running system command in Java:

```
final Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Is it possible to test whether a command exists before running it in Java?

Comment: I am using Windows XP

Comment: You will have to find and parse them from the echo %PATH%

Comment: Just run command in command prompt man , before try it in code.

Comment: `where {command}` returns path if exist. or check does file exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend:

1) Execute the command and check to see if it matches the 'command not found' string that Windows reports back if the command isn't found.

2) Use `System.getenv("PATH")` to get the Windows PATH variable. Split out the PATH into individual directories. Search each directory for an executable with the name of the command you're looking for.

```
    for(String folder : System.getenv("PATH").split(";")) {
        // Look for the executable
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You can run command and check exit code. However obviously some command can change the system state, so you cannot run them safely. For example do not try to check whether command `format c:` is supported :).

However since you are on windows you can either create/find a kind of database of supported commands for specific version or probably run  `help YOUR_COMMAND` to check whether command is here. You can also go according to convention that typically windows commands support option `/?` and/or `/h` that just shows help.

You can also base your decision on error message "The system cannot find command specified" vs. any other error message.

EDIT:
as it is mentioned by @Hitham S. AlQadheeb you can try to search for relevant `.exe` file in path directories and in current directory. This is however cannot give you 100% correct result because some system commands are not represented by relevant file. For example as far as I remember there is no file `dir.exe` but the command `dir` is definitely supported.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the suggestions. Here is my solution:

```
public static String getCmdPathFileStr(String command) {
    String rtn = null;
    if (command != null) {
        String[] sCmdExts = { "", ".com", ".exe", ".bat" };
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(System.getenv("PATH"), File.pathSeparator);
        String path, sFile;
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            path = st.nextToken();
            for (String sExt : sCmdExts) {
                sFile = path + File.separator + command + sExt;
                if (new File(sFile).isFile()) {
                    rtn = sFile;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return rtn;
}
```